# Is there a Code for Displaying table with live items count on the page using tampermoneky

Tags: javascript, java, typescript

Is there a way I can create a tampermonkey script that Shows live data in table which is fetched from another website.

Say, X website has C and B items and it keeps updating.

I want Y website to show a small table with the following information from X website. It'll refresh every 5 seconds.

| Column C | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Items | Items |
| item's | items |

I tried to search for this but nothing seems to work

Comment: ChatGPT is good at writing tampermonkey scripts.